# retrieveallfiles modification

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to parse through a specific Folder to see if a folder title exists.  if not, then I want to create it.

The following v2 c# code will list every single file on my Google Drive just file.  How can I modify it to only return the file list for a single  folder (using the Folders resource ID)?   I do understand that everything is a file, including folders.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Retrieve a list of File resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service">Drive API service instance.</param>
    /// <returns>List of File resources.</returns>
    public static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(DriveService service)
    {
        List<File> result = new List<File>();
        FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();

        do
        {
            try
            {
                FileList files = request.Fetch();

                result.AddRange(files.Items);
                request.PageToken = files.NextPageToken;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                request.PageToken = null;
            }
        } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `q` [search parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters) to restrict your results to files belonging to a single folder as in the following example:

```
'1234567' in parents
```

where '1234567' is the Folder ID.

To perform the same query in C#, you can use the following code:

```
FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
request.Q = "'1234567' in parents";
```

As an alternative, if you only need the IDs of the files in a folder, you can use the [Children feed](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list):

```
ChildrenResource.ListRequest request = service.Children.List(folderId);
ChildList children = request.Fetch();
```